# Checking data of datebox as string are between two dates as strings in mysql

Tags: mysql

the values dateboxes are saving as string t3 and t4 in database sql.The date in mysql has this format:20140215 when retrieved from database.And the date format of dateboxes as string t3 and t4 are changed into 20140215 to save in database.When I want to checks the value of t3 from datebox is included between t3 and t4 from database,how to check this condition?

Comment: don't store dates as strings. Even though your format is (luckily) in a format that allows for quick range comparisons, it's best to use native date/datetime values in the database. `SELECT ... WHERE $datebox BETWEEN t3 AND t4`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am okey by using this coding format. thank you.